I implemented md5 in cuda, but it returns the wrong hash?
I am trying to implement md5 in cuda, here is the code:
__device__ uint32_t K[] = 
{   0xd76aa478,0xe8c7b756,0x242070db,0xc1bdceee,0xf57c0faf,0x4787c62a,
    0xa8304613,0xfd469501,0x698098d8,0x8b44f7af,0xffff5bb1,0x895cd7be,
    0x6b901122,0xfd987193,0xa679438e,0x49b40821,0xf61e2562,0xc040b340,
    0x265e5a51,0xe9b6c7aa,0xd62f105d,0x02441453,0xd8a1e681,0xe7d3fbc8,
    0x21e1cde6,0xc33707d6,0xf4d50d87,0x455a14ed,0xa9e3e905,0xfcefa3f8,
    0x676f02d9,0x8d2a4c8a,0xfffa3942,0x8771f681,0x6d9d6122,0xfde5380c,
    0xa4beea44,0x4bdecfa9,0xf6bb4b60,0xbebfbc70,0x289b7ec6,0xeaa127fa,
    0xd4ef3085,0x04881d05,0xd9d4d039,0xe6db99e5,0x1fa27cf8,0xc4ac5665,
    0xf4292244,0x432aff97,0xab9423a7,0xfc93a039,0x655b59c3,0x8f0ccc92,
    0xffeff47d,0x85845dd1,0x6fa87e4f,0xfe2ce6e0,0xa3014314,0x4e0811a1,
    0xf7537e82,0xbd3af235,0x2ad7d2bb,0xeb86d391 
};

__device__ int s[] = { 7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,7,12,17,22,5,9,14,20,5,9,14,20,
    5,9,14,20,5,9,14,20,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,4,11,16,23,
    6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21,6,10,15,21 };

__device__ uint32_t rotl(uint32_t x, int s) {
    return (x << s) | (x >> (32 - s));
}

__global__ void md5transform(uint32_t M[], uint32_t* state)
{
    uint32_t a = 0x67452301;
    uint32_t b = 0xefcdab89;
    uint32_t c = 0x98badcfe;
    uint32_t d = 0x10325476;
    uint32_t F, g;
    for (int k = 0; k < 64; ++k)
    {
        if (k <= 15)
        {
            F = (b & c) | (~b & d);
            g = k;
        }
        else if (k >= 16 && k <= 31)
        {
            F = (d & b) | (~d & c);
            g = ((5 * k) + 1) % 16;
        }
        else if (k >= 32 && k <= 47)
        {
            F = b ^ c ^ d;
            g = ((3 * k) + 5) % 16;
        }
        else if (k >= 48)
        {
            F = c ^ (b | ~d);
            g = (7 * k) % 16;
        }

        uint32_t dtemp = d;
        d = c;
        c = b;
        b = b + rotl((a + F + K[k] + M[g]), s[k]);
        a = dtemp;
    }
}

I call the kernel in the main function like this:
uint32_t* d_M;        // Input message block (16 words)
uint32_t* d_state;    // Output hash state
uint32_t h_M[16] = { 0 };  // Input message block initialized to zero
uint32_t h_state[4] = { 0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476 };  // Initial state


cudaMalloc((void**)&d_M, 16 * sizeof(uint32_t));
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_state, 4 * sizeof(uint32_t));


cudaMemcpy(d_M, h_M, 16 * sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_state, h_state, 4 * sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//////////// Launch the kernel with 1 block and 1 thread
md5transform << <1, 1 >> > (d_M, d_state);


cudaMemcpy(h_state, d_state, 4 * sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// Print the final MD5 hash state
printf("MD5 Hash (hex): ");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%08x", h_state[i]);
}
printf("\n");


cudaFree(d_M);
cudaFree(d_state);
system("pause");
return 0;

However, this code, when all message blocks are set to zero, gives the hash 031f1dac81f700f38a0fa865671e40c7 and not the infamous zero-input hash of md5, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
My question is, with "zero-input", does that too need padding? So the message block M should be 80000.......00001? But when I do that, it then too does not return the correct hash. The md5 transform function I have copied from here: https://gist.github.com/ameerkat/07a748c9b571289711ebaf61f4b596e9 not all of it, just the compression function, since the code in the link is in c#. However, I feel like I am missing a simple detail or something. When I google the hash my code produces, I get no result in google.

My first debug step would be to remove cuda from the equation, does the same code work correctly in standard c++?

Yes, i tested that and it works

When I transform your code to do the same work in host and device, I get the same print-out.  So the issue here is not CUDA, but your hash algorithm.  Here is an example.  If that were my code, I would not bother with CUDA until I had gotten the c++ code to output the expected result.
